# Is it the same time, does time pass at the same pace everywhere in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, time, big-bang, observers

According to big bang cosmology, the universe has a beginning, a definite age. Does this mean that it is the same time, that time passes at the same pace everywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doesn't dating the universe violate the concept of spacetime's inseparability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192087/)

Comment: cosmology is **based** on general relativity and special relativity, where the definition of time is frame dependent, on the observer and the metric. https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00951